# *Allah* is greatest, *God* is greatest

Tags: arabic, adhan

I am reading the Shi'a version of the Adhan on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhan) (I don't speak arabic).

- **Arabic**

الله أكبر

- **Transliteration**

Allāhu akbar, Allāhu akbar

- **Translation**

Allah is greatest, God is greatest.

---

In the transliteration, the term "Allāhu" is repeated twice and it is one translated by "Allah" and once by "God" which is surprising. Reading from the Adhan again, it rather appears that the term "God" in the general sense is rather translated into "ilāha" I am also surprised not to see the same signs repeated twice.

**Is there any good reason to use once "Allah" and once "God" in the translation?**

Comment: Maybe to show that Allah means (the) God!

Comment: Probably to please everyone, people thinking Allah is the valid translation, and people thinking God is the valid translation.

Comment: Related: http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30935/22

Comment: @goldPseudo I would be happy to close the post as duplicate of the post you linked. I am flagging my post as a duplicate. Thank you all!